# Make this a one-liner: `return sum[dict.get(char) for char in word]`

Tags: python

Obviously, the title has code that can't be interpreted. An uninformative

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

stderr message didn't tell me much, so I threw it in line by line, using:

```
[dict.get(['val','val','foo'])]
```

and have since discovered that `dict.get()` and iterables don't play well together.

If you haven't already guessed, I'm in the exciting field of building toy programs for learning and amusement. Here's my code:

```
def wordpoints(word):
    points = 0
    for char in word:
        points += dict.get(char)
    return points
```

Here's what I want:

```
def wordpoints(word):
    return sum[dict.get(char) for char in word]
```

For clarification, `dict` is named `tile_p` in my code, and stands for tile points. There is another `def` that looks up the scrabble player's dictionary for `True|False` results in a MySQL table, and passes it to this function if it `cursor.fectchone()` has something in it.

Comment: To call the function `sum()`, you should use the function call operator `()`.  Enclose the argument in parens!

Comment: If `dict` is named `tile_p` in your code, why is it named `dict` in your question?

Comment: What's the contents of `dict` (or `tile_p`)? Also I hope you're never using "dict" as a variable name as it's a reserved word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses, not brackets, to call a function:

```
def wordpoints(word):
    return sum(dict.get(char) for char in word)
```

The parser actually told you a bit more than just "invalid syntax":

```
    return sum[dict.get(char) for char in word]
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

See the little `^`?  It points to the token that cause parsing to fail.  Up to this point, all is fine for the parser:  It sees a name (`sum`) followed by the subscription operator `[]`.  Inside the brackets, it expects an arbitrary expression.  Up to `dict.get(char)`, this is a valid expression, but the following token `for` does not make sense to the parser -- hence the syntax error at this point.